# Keep newlines in text blob but limit to one line

Tags: html, css

I have a table, where each row in said table is has a description, and that description could be something like:

```
This is an example:
    - Example 1
    - Example 2
    - Example 3
```

Now I would like to limit the description to 1 line, have overflow: hidden on it, and keep the linebreaks, so that no matter what `- Example 1` is never shown.

I would like to do this in pure CSS + HTML if possible.

I've already tried the following:

```
.overflowing-description {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: pre-line;
    max-height: 30px;
    max-width: 20%;
}
```

Both max-width and max-height did not do anything, so I'm assuming that its the `white-space: pre-line` that is overwriting something here.

jsbin example:
https://jsbin.com/nowuxot

```css
th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.overflowing-description {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre-line;
  max-width:5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>
         name
       </th>
       <th>
         price
       </th>
       <th>
         description
       </th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>
       Example
     </td>
     <td>
       123
     </td>
     <td class="overflowing-description">
       asd asd asd asd 
       asd
       asd
       asd
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       Example
     </td>
     <td>
       123
     </td>
     <td class="overflowing-description">
       asd asd asd asd 
       asd
       asd
       asd
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       Example
     </td>
     <td>
       123
     </td>
     <td class="overflowing-description">
       asd asd asd asd 
       asd
       asd
       asd
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One comment - you can't change height of `td`. Put the text in `p`:

```
<td><p class="overflowing-description">asd asd asd asd</p></td>
```

Secondly, this is enough to hide next lines and preserve line breaks:

```
.overflowing-description {
    max-height: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

As for showing the ellipsis, I once saw a solution with JavaScript that adds it automatically, but there is also some possibility with pure CSS. See [that link](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/).

## Update

There is also a "draft" CSS property that does it, and it seems to be well-supported: `-webkit-line-clamp`.

More more in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp).